# How to get all network interfaces in java and store the information in Java Map

Tags: java

I'm new to Java programming. I need a way to get all network interfaces in Linux using java and store that information in Java `Map`. I found many ways in Google how to do this in a static way - just how to get `eth0` and display the information. My code needs to be portable - the code must display the configuration deployed on server with 2 or 4 network ports.

I thing that the best way to do this is to use Java `Map` to get the information and then later on display it. Would you please help me?

Best Wishes

Comment: what has a `Map` to do with acquiring network interface information?

Comment: I'm not sure there is a portable way to do this. For a similar need (getting the MAC address), I used a ProcessBuilder with 3 different commands for linux, Mac and Windows.

Comment: By portable I mean to get all the information from servers with different number of network ports.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```java
Enumeration<NetworkInterface> interfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
while(interfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
    NetworkInterface networkInterface = interfaces.nextElement();
    Enumeration<InetAddress> inetAddresses = networkInterface.getInetAddresses();
    // ...
}
```

[Here's the documentation for `NetworkInterface`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/net/NetworkInterface.html).

Here is some example code:
http://java.dzone.com/news/network-interface-details-java

Comment: And of course before while() loop you should create whatever collection you need - e.g. Map or List. Then inside while loop just get needed information from networkInterface and put it into your collection (Map, List, etc)