# Using which network interface each Java program uses?

Tags: java, linux

If I have 2 public IPs on a linux system they get represented as virtual network interface names. This is what Linode says about it.

> Linodes have one network interface, eth0. When you add IP addresses,
>   you create virtual network interfaces named eth0:1, eth0:2... eth0:n.

I need to use 2 different Java apps on the same Linode and I want each of them to use a different public IP. I would need to specify which network interface each Java instance uses. Would this be possible? I'm using Debian Linux.

Comment: See this for enumerating network interfaces and check their multiple ip addresses http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102108/how-to-get-all-network-interfaces-in-java-and-store-the-information-in-java-map?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`ServerSocket(int port, int backlog, InetAddress address)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#ServerSocket%28int,%20int,%20java.net.InetAddress%29) constructor to create a server socket bound to a particular IP address (3rd parameter). The address determines the network interface that will be used.

For example:

```
String ip = "192.168.1.54"; // read from config file
int port = 9090;            // likewise
InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port, -1, addr);
```

If you have two different apps and two different IP addresses you'll likely want one app to always use one IP, and the other app to always use the other one. To make sure this association doesn't change you should store the IP address each app is supposed to use in a configuration file or something similar.

Comment: [Network Inteface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html) class lets you find out the interfaces, their IP addresses and check if they are up.